# Copying and replacing text using previous element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to move the **div.heading** that sits directly above each table into the **span.date-span** directly below it replacing the date.

```
<div class="heading"><a href="#">Film number one</a></div>
<table class="table">
<tr class="tablerow">
<td class="tablecell">
<span class="date-span">Fri 18 Jun</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div class="heading"><a href="#">Film number two</a></div>
<table class="table">
<tr class="tablerow">
<td class="tablecell">
<span class="date-span">Sat 19 Jun</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am using the following code but that copies and replaces the first heading into all .date-span. I thought it would be as easy as adding a .prev() but I can't seem to get that to work.

```
$('.date-span').html($('.heading').html());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this solution 
that get parent table of each span then get the element before this table to get its html
and append it to the span

```
$('.date-span').each(function(i, e) {
   $(this).html($(this).parents('table').prev().html());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the span date elements & then iterate over them to set their parent html text like this

`$('.span-date').each((index, element) => {
   var $element = $(element);
   $element.html($element.parents('.heading').html());
 })`

Comment: Thanks, but couldn't get this to work.  I've used the solution by @ahmed Yousif